# Why is $\frac{\cos(\alpha + \beta) + \cos(-\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha + \beta) + \sin(-\alpha)}$ independent of $\alpha$?

Tags: trigonometry, roots-of-unity

By accident I found (numerically) that the expression

$$\frac{\cos(\alpha + \beta) + \cos(-\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha + \beta) + \sin(-\alpha)}$$

only depends on $\beta$. This looks like it shouldn't be hard to prove, but I didn't manage. Can someone think of a nice proof?

Additionally, I would be interested in any geometric interpretation of this result.

Comment: I don't believe that this is true. If $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=\pi/2$, then the expression is $1$. If $\alpha=\pi/2$ and $\beta=0$, then the expression is $0$.

Comment: Did you try using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities

Comment: @JoshB. I think you misread

Comment: You're absolutely right, I did misread. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(-\alpha)=2\cos{\frac{\alpha+\alpha+\beta}{2}}\cos{\frac{\alpha+\beta-\alpha}{2}}=2\cos{\frac{\beta}{2}}\cos\left(\alpha+\frac{\beta}{2}\right)$$

$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\sin(-\alpha)=2\sin{\frac{\alpha+\beta-\alpha}{2}}\cos{\frac{\alpha+\beta-(-\alpha)}{2}}=2\sin{\frac{\beta}{2}}\cos\left(\alpha+\frac{\beta}{2}\right)$$

Comment: I think you should put parentheses around $\alpha + \frac \beta 2$